# Тег XMP как его стилизовать?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем известно что что бы вывести код на страницу нужно воспользоваться тегом `xmp` но как его стилизовать ? к примеру сделать его красиво , ведь css он не слушает .
Как выводить его в рамочке примерно как делают это на многих сайтах ? Подскажите как это реализовать

Comment: Почему-то работает http://jsfiddle.net/cyxa3kfe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните тег `xmp` в `div` и стилизуйте его

```
<div class="xmp">
    <xmp>
    <a id="home" href="/" title="JSFiddle ">
      JSFiddle
      <span>α</span>
    </a>
    </xmp>
</div>
```

Стиль

```
.xmp {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

Такая конструкция одинаково отображается и в IE11, и в FF 40 http://jsfiddle.net/chLz9b19/

В отличии от этого примера http://jsfiddle.net/cyxa3kfe/

Comment: Других браузеров не установлено на компьютере, возможно там могут быть отличия.